# WCF TCP Binding setup between IIS and Service

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, wcf, nettcpbinding

I developed a WCF service, and now reading about the bindings. It s said that TCP binding is the fastest one, which i like to use, but it requires WCF to WCF communication? What s that exactly means?

I have a an application that s on IIS 7, using ASP.NET and a WCF service. they are on different machines. can i use TCP binding?

When i try tcp binding from client (IIS 7) to WCF service, i m getting connection error.

is it possible to connect to WCF service using **only** tcp binding from another server with IIS 7?

if there is , how to do it? I open the port on firewall etc. oh , wcftestclient works, my app doesnt. :(

**again, CLIENT IS ASP.NET PAGE, SERVICE IS WCF, in the SAME NETWORK.**

Comment: Can you please re-state this part of your question: "is it possible to connect to WCF service using only tcp binding from another server with IIS 7?". Specifically, "from a other server with IIS" What does that mean? Please be as clear and explicit as possible.

Comment: "Getting connection error" says nothing. If you want to receive some help you must show the error message. Also you should use WCF tracing to get some more details: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIS uses http. So if your intent is to communicate from a WCF client to an ASP.NET application you should use the http binding. In IIS7, you have to manually go through a series of steps to enable non-HTTP bindings, but it's possible. This MSDN article show you how you can do this
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx

If your client application is the ASP.NET application then yes, you should be able to use TCP binding between you ASP.NET application (that is acting as a WCF client) and your other application that is NOT an ASP.NET application but a regular application that is a WCF service

What you might want to try is build a console application as your WCF client using TCP binding and then:

1. Run it from the same box as your service and ensure things are working correctly.
2. Run it from the IIS box against your WCF service running on the other box and see if it works.

If both these work then it should work from your ASP.NET application as well.

Comment: i m sorry did u read and understand my question. ASP.NET is the client, WCF is the service, they are in the same network.

Comment: ok cool. thanks for the edit and the answer. but i m having problems with the setup. i m getting connection problem. is there an example you would recommend i can follow for setup?

Comment: How do you mean set up? What set up? I'm sorry I don't follow. Your WCF test client you mentioned, is it using TCP binding? Where did you run it from?

Comment: for example, when i use the wcftestclient that comes with windows, everything works fine, when i try to access to wcf from the asp client, it s throwing timeout errors, and service is down errors, even though the service is working .

Comment: Ok, Well, I still think you should build your own "test" client as a simple console application. and follow the steps I mentioned in my answer. It will also give you more information on what is possibly going wrong and more information for anyone here to help you.

Comment: Have you modified your web.config file to include the serviceModel section describing your endpoint? I just build a simple ASP.NET application and WCF client and service and it works just fine. Of course I'm running it on the same machine and had to enable the WCF service application in the Firewall. But the concept works.